# can you explain this process step by step?

Tags: c++

This is the original code and I want to pass all the arguments through `ivlpp_main` using `argc` and `argv`.

```
static void build_preprocess_command(int e_flag)
{
    ivlpp_main(argc, argv);
    snprintf(tmp, sizeof tmp, "%s%civlpp %s%s -F\"%s\" -f\"%s\" -p\"%s\" ",
               pbase, sep, verbose_flag?" -v":"",
               e_flag?"":" -L", defines_path, source_path,
               compiled_defines_path);    
}
```

This is my code

```
static void build_preprocess_command(int e_flag)
{
    char  arg0[] = "%s%civlpp";
    char  arg1[] = "%s%s";
    char  arg2[] = "-F\”%s\”";
    char  arg3[] = "-f\”%s\”";
    char  arg4[] = "-p\”%s\”";
    char  arg5[] = "-v";
    char  arg6[] = "-L";
    char **argv[] = { &arg0[0], &arg1[0], &arg2[0], &arg3[0], &arg4[0], &arg5[0], &arg6[0],  NULL };
    int   argc   = 7;//(int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;
    ivlpp_main(argc,argv);
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of `ivlpp_main` (how it is declared) ?

Comment: @imon: Have you tried compiling? There is usually a simple rule of thumb: if the compiler does not like it, most probably is incorrect. Note that this is not symmetric: if the compiler accepts it, it might still be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> My code is correct or not? – imon

Shouldn't it be,

```
char *argv[] = { ... };  // single pointer array
int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]); // to make it less error prone
```

Also you should pass `&argv`,

```
ivlpp_main(argc,&argv); // assuming ivlpp_main() is like main()
```

Comment: No on the count and the NULL termination. If you want to keep the semantics of `argc` and `argv` in `main`. `argc` is the count of actual arguments, and `argv` is an *array* of `char*` with all the arguments plus a terminating `NULL`. The semantics in the opening question are correct. Then you are right on the type of the array.